# How to Print A Mysql database table into Jtable using Model.addColumn or addItem method in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

How to Print A Mysql database table into Jtable using Model.addColumn or addItem method in java netbeans.

i want to show whole db table into Jtable and on a perticular button i'm delete all the DB table data.

```
 public Display() {
    initComponents();

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    output();
    output1();
}
public void output(){
    try{
            //DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tbloutput.getModel();
            conn=DB_connection.ConnectDB();
            String sql="SELECT * FROM output";
            pst =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int i=0;
        while(rs.next())
            {
                EBF1[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF1");
                EBF2[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF2");
                EBF3[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF3"); 
                EBF5[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF5");
                EBF10[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF10");
                EBF20[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF20");
                EBF30[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF30");
                EBF40[i] = rs.getFloat("EBF40");

                i++;
            }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:"+e);
       }finally{
            try{
                pst.close();
                rs.close();
                conn.close();
             }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error close");
               }
        }
    }

 public void output1(){
    try{
            DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)tbloutput.getModel();
                model.addColumn(EBF1);
                model.addColumn(EBF2);
                model.addColumn(EBF3);
                model.addColumn(EBF5);
                model.addColumn(EBF10);
                model.addColumn(EBF20);
                model.addColumn(EBF30);
                model.addColumn(EBF40);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }
 }
```

and
can i merge Output() and output1() ?

Comment: please help me.....i am in Trouble

Comment: i am doing above code but its not working.